# Can AngularJS and Angular 4 coexist?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have most of the pages created in AngularJS 1.2.26 in my application which is created in MVC4. Now I want to create new pages which can use Angular 4. However few of the pages are common popup and I want to avoid rewriting this pages so iI tried using same master page with AngularJS  and Angular 4 Javascript files. AngularJS pages are working fine.

I would like to know if anyone of you has done this without using AngularJS upgrade? As using Angular upgrade of Angular 4.3.4 shows some errors please provide your opinion on this. Also I have not used AngularJS routing in my existing pages.

Comment: `without using AngularJS upgrade` <= The `angular` team created the `angularjs` upgrade so that `angular` and `angularjs` could coexist and even use each other's already built modules (components, services, etc). If you have errors than you are not using it correctly and you should look into fixing those errors. It should not be standard practice to write your own framework/language/etc. any time you encounter an error in the one you are using. If you don't know how to fix the errors than a good start would be to include the error information in your question.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation: currently have an AngularJS 1.2 app and plan to update to Angular 4 (but haven't done so). However, I think it's better to first update it to AngularJS 1.6 (or at least 1.3) because a lot has changed since then and your issues might be related to that.

Comment: @igor i understand your point but angular 1.2.26 does not support component rather uses directive so migration/ up gradation requires rewriting of code which i want to avoid